# ExtJS 7.5.1 Ext.form.field.Number comma decimalSeparator and numpad

Tags: extjs

i use Ext.form.field.Number with decimalSeparator set to comma but i want to use the dot key from numpad instead of comma key (because this key is far from number keys 0 to 9). No found solution. Any idea, please ?

when i key press dot key from numpad nothing happens but i want a comma inside the visual component